# HTML Double Curved Tab Design

Tags: html, css, tabs

Any way to do this kind of tab design? I can't seem to get my hands on good code online to accomplish it. There's two border-radius for each tab. IS it even possible?

[image: Tab Design]

Comment: Why not view the source of that website to see how they did it?

Comment: Yes that would be a good idea, can you give us the link at least?

Comment: This is a design from my very own designer. So it has not been implemented yet in code. I realize I had wrong wording. Sorry. But yeah. This design is from my designer.

Answer (score 1):

A quick Google search for "css curved tabs" gives an excellent article from css-tricks.com as the first hit: [(Better) CSS Tabs With Round Out Borders](https://css-tricks.com/better-tabs-with-round-out-borders/). The code is right there to copy and paste, but here is a summary of the css tricks involved:

- Use the css `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements to create the tab's rounded elements with curved border-radius styles. (These pseudo-elements with `position: absolute` essentially provide two extra drawing layers - think of layering a transparency sheet on top of your tab's `<li>` html element, and drawing your tab's rounded elements on top of that).
- Use clever box-shadow settings on the rounded elements to hide the square edges of the underlying `<li>` element.
- Use slight negative margins on the `<li>` elements to allow the tabs to overlap each other.

This keeps all the css styling on the same element, and is easily configurable with different gradients, color schemes, and styling elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an internal div in each tab and set border for that.set border for your main tab and now you have two border

Answer (score -1):

It's definitely possible, but a little bit tricky, because the effect has to be simulated somewhat. For example, for the right edge of the middle tab, the top border curve must be defined using `border-radius` on the middle tab, but the bottom curve must be defined using `border-radius` on the *right* tab. The rest of the effect is done by having elements behind the tabs with the appropriate background colors.

Answer (score -1):

There are several ways this could be accomplished with images. You could do background image with a transparent png, for example.